# Question about ultrafilters in a distributive lattice

Tags: order-theory, lattice-orders, filters

Let $p$ and $q$ be distinct ultrafilters (maximal proper filters) in a distributive bounded lattice $L$. Is possible to find $x\in p\setminus q$ and $y\in q\setminus p$ such that $x\vee y = \mathbb{1}$?

Comment: Yes, I will correct.

Comment: No, just consider a chain.

Comment: Usually, the term "ultrafilter" is used in the context of Boolean algebras, where there are (at least) two equivalent  definitions for it: (1) maximal proper filter and (2) prime filter. In more general distributive lattices, these are not equivalent, so you should say which definition you meant. If it's (2), then the comment by @KeithKearnes answers your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $L$ is a bounded chain, then it does not have distinct maximal ideals, and it does not have incomparable prime ideals. Thus, whether "ultrafilter" means "maximal filter" or "prime filter", one cannot choose $x$ and $y$ as desired. But this observation does not answer the following interpretation of the question: Suppose $L$ HAS distinct maximal ideals $p$ and $q$. Is it possible to find $x\in p\setminus q$ and $y\in q\setminus p$ such that $x\vee y = 1$?

The answer to the revised question is also "No" (or, "not necessarily"). Let $L$ be the lattice of finite subsets of the natural numbers with a new top element called $\top$ adjoined. For each $n\in \mathbb N$, the set $F_n$ of all subsets $S\subseteq \mathbb N$ which contain $n$ is a maximal (hence prime) filter. Let $p=F_3$ and $q=F_7$. If $x\in p\setminus q$ and $y\in q\setminus p$, then $x$ and $y$ are finite, so $x\vee y\neq \top$.